# Best database to store locations of users as they move, priority given to read & write speed?

Tags: python, postgresql, memory, redis, memcached

Hi Stack Overflow community, making some architectural decisions & trying to figure out the best strategy to store locations of 50k users who are moving around, in an environment where we care about read & write speed a lot, but don't mind occasionally losing data.

Should one

1. use an in-memory datastore like **Redis** or **Memcached**, or
2. use **Postgres**, with an index on the user_id so that it's fast to insert &
   remove, or
3. use the **filesystem** directly, have a file for each
   user_id, and write to it or read from it to store new locations, or
4. just store the locations **in memory**, in a Python program which
   maintains an ordered list of (user_id, location) tuples

What are the **advantages/ disadvantages** of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had tremendous luck with MySQL and SQLAlchemy.  50k writes per day is nothing.  I write my logs to it, I log my *threads* (think about that, I write logs to it and log each thread) and I process 2.5 million records per day, each generating about 100 logs each.